# List files from distant FTP Server

Tags: files

I'm brand new to the Drupal universe, and I'm stuck on something too big for me ^^ 
I need to create a View or a Content Type that will list files from a distant FTP Server and provide download link to some registered users.

I found something of interest named "Feeds FTP Fetcher", but I just can't find how to display something with it or even if I'm absolutely mistaken with it...

Could you please show me the way to get this "downloadable" list ?

Edit :
I got 2 upvotes and one downvote but still no comments or answers... can you comment below what you need from me ? i can give more details on some points maybe ?